# function loads only on change, i would it to load on document load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My knowledge of this is very limited, but I figured that the problem that I have is in this function. What it does is that it displays some options to be selected in an item post. From what I see it only loads when a category is changed. Because of that when you edit this post, this function will not display unless you change category to another one and then revert back to the one you want. I would like it to display every time, except for those categories that are in the if statement.

Please assist....

```
   $(document).on('change', "#catId", function () {
var optgroups = $(this).children("optgroup[label='Nekretnine'], optgroup[label='Posao'], optgroup[label='Usluge'], optgroup[label='Poljoprivredni oglasi'], optgroup[label='Kućni ljubimci'], optgroup[label='Turizam']");
$(optgroups).each(function(){                               
    if($(optgroups).children("option:selected").length){
        $("#condition-container").html('');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxURL,
            type: "get",
            data: "request=condition-fields",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                if(data) {
                    $("#condition-container").html(data);
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
});
});
```

Comment: it will be much more easy for us to understand your problem if you could have just made a fiddle demo for this.

Comment: I have also trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I wrote something that not even I understand. I apologize.

This is a classifieds website (osclass). When you post a new listing, you have to select a category. Then depending on which category you choose, a div called "condition-container" pops up, giving you choice of "new, used, damaged". This above function displays this div only when you change the category. I would like it to display when the page loads (every time). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to trigger your change event on document load. So under you on change function put this code

```
$(document).on('change', "#catId", function () {
                var optgroups = $(this).children("optgroup[label='Nekretnine'], optgroup[label='Posao'], optgroup[label='Usluge'], optgroup[label='Poljoprivredni oglasi'], optgroup[label='Kućni ljubimci'], optgroup[label='Turizam']");
                $(optgroups).each(function () {
                    if ($(optgroups).children("option:selected").length) {
                        $("#condition-container").html('');
                    } else {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: ajaxURL,
                            type: "get",
                            data: "request=condition-fields",
                            dataType: "html",
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    $("#condition-container").html(data);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            //Trigger change
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $("#catId").trigger("change");
             });
```

Comment: This is the fastest way, but not the way to do it. Define the function and on document load add it on the $(#catId) element on change event. and also call it outside as a  init. This way it would be cleaner.

Comment: @Dinca Adrian if you have a clean and correct answer please post it as an answer, this will help other ppl looking at this post

Answer (score 0):

hi I assume you want the function fired on document load and on change, but for that you will need to use 2 triggers.

1) you allready have the on change trigger

2) use the $(document).ready() (https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) wrapper for onload.

There is possibly a much more gracefull solution, but I'm no JS expert so this will only get you to a working, although not the pretiest state

Comment: Yes, thank you, thats exactly what I want, but since I am no expert, I wouldnt know how exactly to do it, thats where I need assistance.

Comment: Parag Soni gave you exactly that answer, what his code does is runs the function on change, and and on document load, change event is also triggered

Comment: That did the job. Thank you ever so much!